# Can't use React context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, use-context

My `index.js` has:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
        <Suspense fallback="loading">
            <App/>
        </Suspense>
    </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Inside `app.js` I am trying to access the context:

```js
export default function App(props) {
    console.log("app trying to use firebase");
    const {firebase} = useFirebase();
    return <div>{firebase && firebase.loggedIn()}</div>
}
```

FirebaseContext and Firebase class are defined like so:

```js
export const FirebaseContext = createContext({});
export const useFirebase = () => useContext(FirebaseContext);

export default class Firebase {
    constructor() {
        console.log("firebase intialized")
        app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        this.auth = app.auth();
    }

    loggedIn = () => {
        return !!this.auth.currentUser;
    }
}
```

FirebaseContext seems to be initialized properly since I get the output inside the console, but I keep getting Error: Cannot read property 'loggedIn' of undefined.
Why can't I use my context?

Comment: Oops, it was just a typo! Should have been `const firebase = useFirebase();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried your code after removing the destructuring like so

`const {firebase} = useFirebase();` =>>> `const firebase = useFirebase();`

If the issue persists, then try to bind the  **firebase** variable given that loggedIn is resulting in undefined within a class-based component.